# CodeMirror 2: Multiple indent is deleting lines

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have implemented Code Mirror as a plugin into a CMS system.

I have an issue where if I select multiple lines and press tab the lines are deleted.

This does not happen on the Code Mirror demo website. I can't find a configuration option to enable or disable multiple indent.

Here is my configuration code:

```
this.CodeArea = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(codeArea, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: { name: "xml", htmlMode: true },
    onChange : function (editor) {
        editor.save();
    }
});
```

Context: https://github.com/rsleggett/tridion-mirror/blob/master/src/BuildingBlocks.Tridion2011Extensions.CodeMirror/BuildingBlocks.Tridion2011Extensions.CodeMirror/Scripts/codemirror/codemirror.js

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The CodeMirror javascripts differ between [your version](https://github.com/rsleggett/tridion-mirror/blob/master/src/BuildingBlocks.Tridion2011Extensions.CodeMirror/BuildingBlocks.Tridion2011Extensions.CodeMirror/Scripts/codemirror/codemirror.js) and the [demo version](http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js):

In the demo version at around line 2036 there is the following code block that is missing from your version:

```
defaultTab: function(cm) {
    if (cm.somethingSelected()) cm.indentSelection("add");
    else cm.replaceSelection("\t", "end");
}
```

Along with a bunch of functions related to `CodeMirror.keyMap`.

Compare the two and merge the missing bits, or just use the script from the demo version.

Comment: I'm on version 3.15 and it doesn't work for me. The line you refer to in this version differs here: `else cm.replaceSelection("\t", "end", "+input");`. I've tried using `else cm.replaceSelection("\t", "end");` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was happening because I used the custom snippet from CodeMirror official documentation which mapped the Tab  ¡to insert spaces instead of a tab character:

```
editor.setOption("extraKeys", {
  Tab: function(cm) {
    var spaces = Array(cm.getOption("indentUnit") + 1).join(" ");
    cm.replaceSelection(spaces);
   }
});
```

Removing this custom snippet made block tabulation work again and spaces were used instead of tabs by default.